# Unity and ssh -X has no launcher icon

Tags: unity, ssh, launcher

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64-bit.

Whenever I ssh into a client with -X, and launch a program remotely, I can see it and everything works fine, but they have no icon in the launcher.  Therefore, if I minimize the running remote program, there's no way to actually get it back.  Alt+Tab doesn't show it either.

How exactly do I get the running programs back, and/or get the remote programs via ssh -X to actually show up in the launcher?

Thanks.